# dictionaryWithContentsOfFile returning nil from my property list file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, properties, plist, nsdictionary

I'm learning how to use plist files for storing data in my iPhone app.  I've been reading a bunch of the questions about plist and dictionaryWithContentsOfFile on this site, but can't see what I'm doing wrong.

The following line returns nil ("The dictionary is null" to the console).

```
NSLog(@"The dictionary is %@",[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"myFile"]);
```

The myFile.plist file is in the resources folder, and contains a few strings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>john</string>
    <key>aname</key>
    <string>jen</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From the documentation...

> `+ (id)dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *path*
>
> A full or relative pathname. The file identified by path must contain a string representation of a property list whose root object is a dictionary.
>
> **Return Value**
>
> A new dictionary that contains the dictionary at path, or nil if there is a file error or if the contents of the file are an invalid representation of a dictionary.

So, you need to probably construct a full path to your plist file (or pass in an appropriate relative path.  I'd be very surprised if "myFile" is an appropriate relative path).  If you build a proper path but then are still getting `nil` back, then you've probably got an invalid plist file.

The easiest way to get a path for a file in your resources folder is like this:

```
NSString * plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myFile" ofType:@"plist"];
```

That will build a path for a file called "myFile.plist" inside your Resources folder.

Comment: +1 for the mainBundle approach. It hurts my eyes when people tries to find their bundle-path (without `[NSBundle mainBunde]`, of course) and build their own resource-paths...