# Dictionary with contents of file not working in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdictionary, jailbreak

I am trying to get a dictionary from a plist in ios.The problem is the code is not working.It works in a different function but not this one.

```
  NSDictionary* pdata=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:datapath];
```

The file exists at path but for some reason its not working.I get null when I try to print the dictionary.

**EDIT:** Here is my path/private/var/mobile/Applications/F4D5EFE8-58FC-4179-9492-4C4F9FD01024/Library/Preferences/abc.def.ghi.plist.This is a jailbroken application and I was able to do this successfully for another pplist in a seperate location.

Comment: post your datapath code too.. it may help us to answer correctly.

Comment: Can you post the file content or the code that you are using for creating datapath ?

Comment: Check this [link][1], maybe it can help


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895898/dictionarywithcontentsoffile-returning-nil-from-my-property-list-file

Comment: you need to check written plist root file is dictionary or array

Answer (score 1):

This Should Work Fine.

```
 NSString *plistFileUrl=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"someplistFile"      ofType:@"plist"];
 NSURL *url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:plistFileUrl];
 NSDictionary *aDict=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Answer (score 0):

This must work for you.

```
NSString *aStr=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Property List" ofType:@"plist"];
NSURL *aUrl=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:aStr];
NSDictionary *aDict=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:aUrl];
```

Comment: Returns an exception  (*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter)

Comment: Check for the name.I have created abc.def.ghi.plist and tested,it works here for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .

```
NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                                                                           pathForResource:@"example" ofType:@"plist"]isDirectory:NO]];
    NSLog(@"data is %@",dict);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 //Local mainbundle
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *filePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Contents.plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *dictContent = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSLog(@"%@",dictContent);


  ///DocumentsDirectory
NSMutableDictionary *dictItem=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dictItem setObject:@"ravi" forKey:@"name"];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *docFilePath = [documentsDirectoryPath
                      stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];
[dictItem writeToFile:docFilePath atomically: YES];

NSMutableDictionary *dictContent1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:docFilePath];
NSLog(@"%@",dictContent1);
```